# Don't resolve typedefs in Visual Studio 2022 tooltips

Tags: c++, visual-studio, typedef, code-analysis

My program includes OpenCV headers. As a result, Visual Studio resolves a simple `std::vector<int>` as this:

[image]

How can I force Visual Studio to ignore typedefs when detecting the type of a variable?

Comment: I dont know VS, but to me this looks like nothing about typedef. Its just a variable with same name (but different type)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai  I can reproduce it with even more simple code: `#include <vector>` and then `using my_type = std::vector<int>; std::vector<int> vec;` When you hover the mouse over the `vec`, IntelliSense displays `my_type vec`, despite this not being the case.

Comment: @heapunderrun in your example `vec` is of type `my_type`. In OPs screenshot `X` seems to be the name of a variable

Comment: There are about zero intellisense customization options in Visual Studio. You can report  post to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp) so developers are aware.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The tooltip means "you are hovering over a variable with name `X` and type `cv::dnn::[...]::MatShape`", it doesn't means "this is the same as another variable with name `X` and type `[...]`".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai See what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBRQ2.png (in my example, `vec` is of type `std::vector<int>`, but when hovered over `vec`, it shows `my_type vec`, not `std::vector<int> vec`).

Comment: Is there any update? You could report the problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp): Suggest a Feature and  post link here.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I don't have time to make a repro case right now but I plan to report it. Thanks for checking in :)